# Op-amp comparator

Tags: comparator

I am modeling a comparator as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fN2Fan.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So I want the following:  if V15=0, then the output should be 0.  But if V15=5, then it should output some Vcc (which I have as 12).  When I simulate this, I only get + or -12 at the output, so I am not sure where I have errored.

Comment: Your OpAmp is supplied with -12 and +12 V, so '0' will be -12 V and '1' will be +12 V.

Comment: Opamps don't make good comparators, and 741's aren't good opamps. So even though you might get this to work in a simulator, don't expect it to translate well into a real circuit.

Answer (score 3):

This is expected behavior with split supplies.  (It looks like you are using a 741 op-amp model which isn't the best comparator model.) In any case a comparator can only swing to its positive rail or negative rail, there's no internal circuitry that finds a ground and outputs zero volts.  Some comparators have an unconnected emitter or source transistor in the output stage that can be connected to ground and therefore will output 0V with split supplies, but you have no such device in your model.

Comment: What is a better op amp model?

Comment: You should use a comparator model which is different from an op-amp.  Comparators include the LM339 or LM393 for example.

Comment: @yankeefan11 As JohnD has pointed out, the LM741 output will not swing anywhere near the rails, *despite what the simulator says*. The LM741 model that Circuitlab uses is actually very poor and doesn't not reflect the actual performance of the op-amp. Pick a real comparator, and be wary of trusting the simulator.

Answer (score 2):

In any comparator, when the + input goes more positive than the - input, (or the - input goes more negative than the + input) the output will go high, and when the - input goes more positive than the + input, (or the + input goes more negative than the - input)  the output will go low.

Therefore, you've made a fundamental error in expecting the output to go low when V15 is equal to zero volts and the comparator's + input is sitting at + 2.5 volts.

Comment: Also a good point.

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKQ1Qf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have removed the power supplied to simplify the circuit, but this will do as you desire

Comment: Would the output of the second OpAmp be able to drive a 12V relay?  Or how could i set that up?

Comment: Use the opamp (with split supplies if you need to) to drive an NPN transistor: Opamp output -- 1k -- Base. Emitter = GND (0 V), collector = output. You can use a pull-resistor to +supply if you need. Now the output will go 0 to + supply. To drive a relay you'll need a clamp for the inductive spikes, or a diode across the relay coil.

Answer (score -1):

Simply remove your V18 source and connect this pin to ground.

Comment: I thought I had done that, but I guess not

Comment: That might work with no load on the output, but if the OP is really using a 741 op-amp model that can only get to within 2-3V of ground with any appreciable current sourcing load on the output.  It won't make a good comparator.

Answer (score -1):

There are several problems with your circuit:

You have the inputs wired backwards.  If you want the output to go high when the input is high, then V15 should be connected to the + input of the opamp and the reference connected to the - input.

200 Ω for the voltage divider to make the reference voltage is much lower than necessary.  Inputs of ideal opamps don't draw any current, so the signal can be high impedance.  The 741 is far from ideal, but it doesn't need anywhere as low as 50 Ω impedance driving one of its inputs.

Use two 10 kΩ resistors.  That presents 20 kΩ to the power supply, and 5 kΩ to the opamp, which is still plenty low enough.

A 741 opamp is totally inappropriate here.  Something like a MCP6021, for example, would make lot more sense here.

You don't want a negative voltage for the opamp's negative supply.  This is what is causing the output to go to -12 V when low.  Tie the negative supply pin to ground.  Of course that means you can't use a 741, but you shouldn't anyway.

With the above changes, you should get a fairly crisp 0 V or 5 V output depending on whether the input voltage is above or below the threshold.

To drive a relay, have the opamp output drive a transistor, which then drives a relay.  This has been discussed many times here before.  Search for *"How to on/off da reelaiy thingy from my arduino?"* or similar.  Let me know if you can't find something suitable.

Comment: LOL- "How to on/off da reelaiy thingy from my arduino?"